# Minimizing average distance

Tags: r, optimization

I am working on a function that can give a vector *a*, find a set of values *b*  where the average distance of values in *a* to the closest value in *b* is minimal. In other words, I want to find the ideal spread for a fixed number of points across a distribution, so the average distance is minimal. I hope this explanation makes sense to people.

The function below accepts two arguments: the vector *a* and *p* which is the length of *b*. It works as intended for *p* = 2, but produces an error for any larger number of *p* (See the error below). The error makes no sense to me as it should not be possible that the two vectors have different lengths. (mc)lapply running Closest over the vector *a* should always produce a vector of the same length as *a* so I have no clue how to fix this issue.

```
library(DescTools)
library(stats)
library(parallel)

party_opt <- function(a, p) {
dist_f <- function(a, b) {
  dist <- mean(abs(a - unlist(mclapply(a, function(i) Closest(x = b, a = i)), use.names=FALSE)))
  return(dist)
}
out <- optim(par = rep(min(a),p), fn = dist_f,  a = a)
return(out)
}
```

This is the error that occurs with more than two values.

Warning messages:

> 1: In people - unlist(mclapply(a, function(i) Closest(x = b, a = i)),
> :   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: This is like a facility location problem. These models are not so easy to solve to optimality. Even with high performance MISOCP (Mixed-Integer second order cone programming) solvers. Your approach will not work very well in practice (nonconvex formulation).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I managed to produce a version that runs, but results are really unreliable using Nelder-Mead optimization. So you would recommend MISOCP  for a problem like this? I need it for application in social science, so as long as there is some measure of how well the optimization worked, that would be ok. The data I use is not as accurate you'd find it in engineering or other fields anyway.

Comment: See https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/01/continuous-facility-location-symmetry.html

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for.